Examples of non-localic topos
A topos is localic if it is a sheaf topos on a locale, or equivalently, every object can be covered by a family of subterminals.
The localic toposes classifies the theory of sentences only, so I imagine a non-localic topos can arise as the classifying topos of some theory. May I please ask if there are non-localic topos arise from elsewhere?

Technically every topos arises as the classifying topos of some geometric theory. So I guess that your question is really about other ways of constructing toposes, besides those two constructions (localic and classifying)? There are many ways, the easiest perhaps being presheaf toposes.

@MarkKamsma Thank you for your rapid response! I would like any example as long as it is concrete so I can get some sense of what it looks like. It would be even better if it comes with an explicit realization as a Grothendieck topos on some site.

I wonder if there might be examples among the standard sites from algebraic geometry, e.g. the etale sites, fppf site, crystalline (or infinitesimal) site, etc. on a scheme.  The Zariski site, of course, coming from a topological space, is localic.  For the others, though, I can't immediately see what restrictions there might be on colimits of subterminals.  (Though in the crystalline/infinitesimal case, certainly differences between two parallel maps play a crucial role in getting a connection on an $\mathscr{O}_{X/S}$-sheaf, vaguely suggesting that case might not be localic.)

There are many ways to construct toposes, besides from locales or (directly) as a classifying topos of some geometric theory. One of the easiest constructions is probably that of a presheaf topos, so toposes of the form $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^\text{op}}$.
You are asking about non-localic toposes, and there are many. However, even if you construct a topos in a different way, it does not mean you couldn't have constructed it as the topos of sheaves on some locale. So that means that after constructing your topos you have to prove that it is indeed non-localic.
Let me give a concrete example. Consider $\mathbb{N}$ as a monoid under addition, and as such we view it as a category in the usual way: there is one object, the arrows are the elements of $\mathbb{N}$ and composition is given by addition. Then $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbb{N}^\text{op}}$ is a topos. It admits a concrete description: its objects are sets with a (right) $\mathbb{N}$-action and the arrows are functions of sets that respect this $\mathbb{N}$-action. Or put differently, objects are pairs $(X, \sigma)$ where $X$ is a set and $\sigma: X \to X$ is a function, and an arrow $f: (X, \sigma) \to (Y, \tau)$ is a function $f: X \to Y$ such that $f(\sigma(x)) = \tau(f(x))$ for all $x \in X$.
So let's now show that $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbb{N}^\text{op}}$ is not localic. The terminal object $1$ is given by the singleton set with the trivial $\mathbb{N}$-action. That means that for any object $X$ in $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbb{N}^\text{op}}$, an arrow $1 \to X$ corresponds to fixed point of $X$ (i.e. an element $x \in X$ that is fixed by the $\mathbb{N}$-action).
Let us now consider the natural numbers as an object of $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbb{N}^\text{op}}$. We will use different notation to distinguish the different roles of $\mathbb{N}$. So $N$ is the object of $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbb{N}^\text{op}}$ that has underlying set $\mathbb{N}$ and whose $\mathbb{N}$-action is given by addition. Note that this is the Yoneda-embedding of the one object in $\mathbb{N}$ considered as a category into $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbb{N}^\text{op}}$.
Then $N$ has no fixed points, and so there are no arrows $1 \to N$. Also note that the only subobjects of $1$ are $1$ itself and the initial object $0$. We conclude that $N$ cannot be covered by a family of subterminals, which shows that $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbb{N}^\text{op}}$ is not localic.
Note that the above trick can easily be generalised by replacing $\mathbb{N}$ by any (non-trivial) monoid.

A similar example, brought up in another recent post to [topos-theory]: The topos of directed graphs.  (Which can be represented as the topos of presheaves on a category with two objects $V,E$ and two morphisms $s,t:V\to E$ plus the two identity morphisms.)  Then the final object has one vertex and one self-loop, so any graph made by colimits from subterminals can only have self-loops as edges.

Thank you both! They are very indeed very minimal and clear examples.
